# Simple Bootstrap Form

Tags: forms, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to reproduce this form:

https://themes.gohugo.io//theme/hugo-terrassa-theme/contact

Using Bootstrap 4 (no Flexbox due to IE11 need):

I'm stuck.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="container ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group ">
                <!-- Name -->
                <label class="control-label" for="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputNameName }}">
                    {{ $.Site.Params.form.inputNameLabel }}</label>
                <div>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputNameName }}"
                           placeholder="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputNamePlaceholder }}"
                           id="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputNameName }}"
                           aria-labelledby="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputNameName }}" required>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group ">
                <!-- Email -->
                <label class="control-label" for="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputEmailName }}">
                    {{ $.Site.Params.form.inputEmailLabel }}</label>
                <div>
                    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputEmailName }}"
                           placeholder="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputEmailPlaceholder }}"
                           id="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputEmailName }}"
                           aria-labelledby="{{ $.Site.Params.form.InputEmailName }}" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col">
                <!-- Message -->
                <label class="control-label" for="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputMsgName }}">
                    {{ $.Site.Params.form.inputMsgLabel }}</label>
                <div>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputMsgName }}"
                          id="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputMsgName }}" form="contactForm"
                          maxlength="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputMsgLength }}" id="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputMsgName }}"
                          arial-labelledby="{{ $.Site.Params.form.InputMsgName }}" required></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Submit -->
        <a class="button" href="javascript:cleanForm" aria-label="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputSubmitValue }}">
            {{ $.Site.Params.form.inputSubmitValue }}
        </a>

    <h6 class="text-center">
        <strong>Phone </strong>{{ .Site.Data.contact.phone }}
        <strong>Fax </strong>{{ .Site.Data.contact.fax }}
    </h6>
</div>
```

I'm somewhat new to the Bootstrap grid but I understand the basic concepts. I've got the labels and the inputs aligning how I want, but I can't figure out how to get the thing centered and spaced like the example.

Note, the embedded values, e.g. {{ .Site.Data.contact.fax }} are getting filled in by the Hugo static site generator system. Also, there is a form element wrapping this container but I don't think that should matter to demonstrate the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use bootstrap [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) and use a series of row and columns to achieve your layout.

I've tested the code below and it provides a layout similar to what you need.

```
<div class="container ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 form-group">
            <!-- Name -->
            <label class="control-label" for="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputNameName }}">{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputNameLabel }}</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputNameName }}" placeholder="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputNamePlaceholder }}" id="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputNameName }}" aria-labelledby="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputNameName }}" required>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 form-group">
            <!-- Email -->
            <label class="control-label" for="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputEmailName }}">{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputEmailLabel }}</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="email" name="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputEmailName }}" placeholder="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputEmailPlaceholder }}" id="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputEmailName }}" aria-labelledby="{{ $.Site.Params.form.InputEmailName }}" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 form-group">
            <!-- Message -->
            <label class="control-label" for="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputMsgName }}">{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputMsgLabel }}</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputMsgName }}" id="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputMsgName }}" form="contactForm" maxlength="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputMsgLength }}" id="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputMsgName }}" arial-labelledby="{{ $.Site.Params.form.InputMsgName }}" required></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Submit -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 form-group text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:cleanForm" aria-label="{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputSubmitValue }}">{{ $.Site.Params.form.inputSubmitValue }}</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h6 class="text-center">
        <strong>Phone </strong>{{ .Site.Data.contact.phone }}
        <strong>Fax </strong>{{ .Site.Data.contact.fax }}
    </h6>
</div>
```